# How to convert string into response object in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to convert a string that contains `html` tags so that I can use `selectors` to extract few information. I'm getting this `html` in a `json` response. I've used `HTMLParser` but I'm getting an error as `exceptions.TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'unicode' object`

My code is:

```
sel = Selector(response)
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
hello= jsonresponse["html"].encode('ascii','ignore')
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
world=h.unescape(hello)
sel1 = Selector(world)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

I just needed to mention `text` while using `Selectors` in case response is a string.

```
sel = Selector(response)
jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
hello= jsonresponse["html"].encode('ascii','ignore')
sel1 = Selector(text=hello)
```

Comment: I usually just do `json.loads(response.body)`